# RDF XML dog properties

Tags: xml, rdf, rdfs

I am trying to create an ontology for animals in RDF(S) XML.In my graph I have currently  classes, subclasses and instances. For example I have a class "dog".
How can I define for the class dog that dogs have: four legs, and that they have fur.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define class `dog`, data property `hasLegs` and then you need to define `Class: dog hasLegs value 4`. I don't know what editor are you using, but for example in protege, you need to find dog and click `subClassOf` and then type `hasLegs value 4`.

[image]

Comment: Should I define dog as a class, and dog1 as instances? I also have Tree as class. Should I define Oak as class and oak1 as instance, or I can do Oak as an instance? Thanks

Comment: If dog1 has a name and is the smallest entity, you need to define it as instance. The same goes for oak1. Generally it if you can't break something anymore down you need to define it as an instance, but it is a modelling decision. You can do either.

Comment: Is this right?

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangutan">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle"></rdfs:domain>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle">
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangutan"></rdfs:range>
</rdf:Description>

Comment: or is it: Orangutang lives in Jungle. Lives has domain Jungle and range Orangutang??? Would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Orangutan lives in Jungle. Lives has domain Jungle and range must be the super-class of Orangutan. Since there are more than one animals living in the jungle and lives will be used for more than one, your range should not be so specific otherwise the reasoner will find lots of unsatisfiable concepts.